# Re rake after you edit a model?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I am just starting my first ruby project. I followed tutorial and built a blog. I thought next i would add a commenting system to extend the project, I just added  has_many :comments to my post model. In the tutorial after we built the model we raked the database. Im not entirely sure what it does, but it seems fairly important. Is this something at I will need to do again  and any time i update a model? I am using the gem 'sqlite3'

thanks

Comment: Can you share exactly which rake function you called/entered in the command line?

Comment: @kendrick nope, its rake db:migrate

Comment: thanks. I was going from memory, and like i said, this is my very first project.

Comment: rake is to ruby what make is to C. See http://rake.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you create a new model (database table) you got to run the migration, which creates the table in the database.  Whenever you make any change to the db, you got to run migrations so as to make sure your db is in sync with your latest changes.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime, you create/edit a model(database table) in rails, you should write a migration for the same. The migration will make the necessary changes to your database once it is run using "rake db:migrate" command.
With the has_many :comments in your blog model. You will need to add a migration to create the comments table, with blog_id as the foreign key, assuming your blog model is called 'blog'.